# Mysql C# Connector/Net MembershipProvider seems to be bug - is it a bug or did i do it wrong

Tags: c#, mysql, membership-provider

I’m learning my way around ASP.NET MVC using vs2010 and .NET4 – nothing for production use, just for my own personal use.

I created a default ASP.NET MVC which comes with pre-existing home page, about page and login and registration pages. In attempting to use the existing login and registration pages I (not having an SQL server) replaced the SQLMembershipProvider with the MySQLMembershipProvider found in Connector/NET in the MySQL.Web.Security.

However this didn’t work straight away, aside from the common issue people seemed to have with autogeneration of the schema (solved by googling) I had two other problems that I noticed.

The first was that if left unset or simply as an empty string, the PasswordStrengthRegularExpression would cause a Null Exception in the MySQLMembershipProvider. I solved that by modifying the providers code to fix the “if” statement where the problem was occurring. (If I recall, it was only checking that the string wasn’t empty, it didn’t check for the string being null)

The second was that the MySQLMembershipProvider has an Initialize method, overridden from the base class, which must be called on each instantiation of the provider. This method was being called only on the very first instantiation but not again afterwards (determined by stepping through the code and use of breakpoints). The provider appears to be instantiated once per page load.

My solution (not the best) has been to modify the MySQLMembershipProvider to create static variables to store the arguments of the call to Initialize and a variable to store whether or not the object has been initialized. I then put a call to the Initialize method at the beginning of every other method. The Initialize method was modified to return instantly if the object had already been initialized.

My query is this: Is the MySQLMembershipProvider flawed and thus the issues I’m describing are bugs or have I misunderstood something and not correctly used the MySQLMembershipProvider?

N.B. If you want to see code, please tell me which bits as 90% of it is auto generated or available from the mysql dev site as source. There is quite a lot.

Comment: Sorry, on reading back through this it doesn't flow very well as a question. I think if I try to revise it now it's not going to help. If someone else doesn't revise it I will make an attempt tomorrow